# SVG exported with Adobe Illustrator to SVG not displaying well in Raphael.js

Tags: html, svg, raphael, adobe-illustrator, eps

I downloaded the Adobe illustrator file from 
http://all-free-download.com/free-vector/vector-misc/animal_character_illustrations_58511.html

and opened in with Adobe illustrator, I then exported it to SVG and tried to display it on an Html page with raphael.js. The SVG was displayed on the html, but it looked corrupted, some colors were changed and lines moved.

Did anyone had any experience with exporting from Illustrator to SVG and user it with Raphael.js. Any idea would be great.

I also tried to use jquery.vectron to show the SVG and also the http://readysetraphael.com/ converter, but same bad result. If someone will try this and tell me what I did wrong would be great

Comment: Is there a particular reason for using Raphael for this? Modern browsers support SVG pretty well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using Raphael.js for IE8=< coverage, I have to note that from your readysetraphael.com link that radialGradients "Radial gradients only render partially accurate" (my SVG generated from the illustrator file contains several).

Comment: So I guess Raphael.js is not always showing SVG well, does anyone know other js library to show svg files?

Comment: Thanks JayC Don't know why I went so far for checking how to display svg with raphael, simple pasted it in the HTML, forgot all new browsers supports it